# vba- Case statements requiring to meet three conditions to execute

Tags: excel, vba, case-statement

I am trying to have my program execute the Case statement only if all three conditions are met. However, it is still executing even if the third one is not met. How can I solve this please? Here is the code:

```
'Scenario 1
Sheet2.Activate 
Range("C4").Select 

ADT = ActiveCell.Value 
Speed = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value 
Nonmotorizedexpected = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value 

SpaceAvailable = ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Value 
MinSpaceNMT = ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0).Value 

UserADT = UserTool.txtADT.Value 
UserSpeed = UserTool.txtSpeed.Value 
UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value 



 Select Case True 
   Case ((UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) And UserNonmotorizedexpected =     Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value) 
    Select Case True 
    Case SpaceAvailable > MinSpaceNMT 
        MsgBox "Safe passage can be within the bridge with Alt. 2.1" 
    Case Else 
        MsgBox "Check next alt." 
    End Select 
   End Select 


'Scenario 5
Sheet2.Activate 
Range("S4").Select 

ADT = ActiveCell.Value 
Speed = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value 
Nonmotorizedexpected = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value 

SpaceAvailable = ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Value 
MinSpaceNMT = ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0).Value 

UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D4").Value 

Select Case True 
Case ((UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) And (UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D4").Value)) 
Select Case True 
Case SpaceAvailable > MinSpaceNMT 
    MsgBox "Safe passage can be within the bridge with Alt. 2.5" 
Case Else 
    MsgBox "Check next alt." 
End Select
```

End Select

The third conditions is UserNonmotorizedexpected. It is different from scenario 1 and 5. However, since the first two conditions are the same is taking both scenarios as solution. I would like the program to take only the one where all three conditions are met.

This is how the code looks like now after comments:

```
'Scenario 3
    Sheet2.Activate
    Range("K4").Select

    ADT = ActiveCell.Value
    Speed = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Nonmotorizedexpected = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value

    SpaceAvailable = ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Value
    MinSpaceNMT = ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0).Value

    UserADT = UserTool.txtADT.Value
    UserSpeed = UserTool.txtSpeed.Value
    UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value

     Select Case True
            Case ((UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed >= Speed) And UserNonmotorizedexpected = Nonmotorizedexpected)
                Select Case True
                    Case SpaceAvailable > MinSpaceNMT
                        MsgBox "Safe passage can be within the bridge with Alt. 2.3"
                    Case Else
                        MsgBox "Check next alt."
                End Select
        End Select
```

Comment: Has my answer been helpful?

Comment: I think my problem is that UserNonmotorizedexpeced is a combo box as string with two options. I didnt really know how to refer to it. I work for (UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) because I was just working with numbers. Is there a way to refer to a specific answer from the combo box?

Comment: Are you saying that the variable, UserNonmotorizedexpected, is an object variable set to an ActiveX combobox? Or are you saying it is a normal Variant variable and you have a validation list combobox in cell D3?

Comment: Hi, UserNonmotorized is a combo box with two anwers (Low/Avg, and High). The combo box answers are in D3 and D4. The code looks like this now:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but the Case statements you have seem to be an attempt to create and If...Then..ElseIf structure.  This is what you should do for better structure (if your code is what I think it is):

```
 .....
 UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value 

 If ((UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) _
        And UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value) Then
      If SpaceAvailable > MinSpaceNMT Then
           MsgBox "Safe passage can be within the bridge with Alt. 2.1" 
      Else 
           MsgBox "Check next alt." 
      End If
 End If

      Sheet2.Activate 
      Range("S4").Select 

      ADT = ActiveCell.Value 
      Speed = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value 
      Nonmotorizedexpected = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value 

     SpaceAvailable = ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0).Value 
     MinSpaceNMT = ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0).Value 

     UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D4").Value
     If ((UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) _
           And (UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D4").Value)) Then
         If SpaceAvailable > MinSpaceNMT Then
                  MsgBox "Safe passage can be within the bridge with Alt. 2.5" 
         Else 
                  MsgBox "Check next alt." 
        End If
     End If
```

However, the real problem that you are having is that in one line you are setting:

```
 UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value
```

and then a couple of lines later you are checking:

```
 If.....And (UserNonmotorizedexpected = Worksheets(7).Range("D3").Value
```

Of course these are going to be equal!  You just set the variable equal to this value!

Perhaps you mean:

```
 If.....And (UserNonmotorizedexpeced = Nonmotorizedexpected)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think my problem is that UserNonmotorizedexpeced is a combo box as string with two options. I didnt really know how to refer to it. I work for (UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) because I was just working with numbers. Is there a way to refer to a specific answer from the combo box?

Comment: What are the values in D3 and D4?  Are these the strings that the combobox is based on?  You can use these, but then you need a different variable to get the value out of the combo box and to check this variable vs the value in the combo box.  For more help in getting the value out of the combo box, you need to answer Excel Hero's question.

Comment: Hi, UserNonmotorized is a combo box with two anwers (Low/Avg, and High). The combo box answers are in D3 and D4. I am having a difficult time validating these strings. Do i have to convert them to integers? (UserADT <=ADT) and (UserSpeed <Speed) were easy to validate because they are numbers. How should i go about validate Strings?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your variables do not contain the values you think they do when the three conditions are tested. Without your workbook, it is impossible to check this for you, but...

Consider this:

```
Select Case True
    Case 1 <= 2 And 2 < 3 And 3 = 3
        Beep
End Select
```

The above is a simplified representation of your logic. Of course a beep is heard when executed.

But no beep is heard here:

```
Select Case True
    Case 1 <= 2 And 2 < 3 And 3 = 4
        Beep
End Select
```

...because the 3rd condition is not met.

Please re-examine  your variables and their types.

Comment: I think my problem is that UserNonmotorizedexpeced is a combo box as string with two options. I didnt really know how to refer to it. I work for (UserADT <= ADT) And (UserSpeed < Speed) because I was just working with numbers. Is there a way to refer to a specific answer from the combo box?

Comment: Are you saying that the variable, UserNonmotorizedexpected, is an object variable set to an ActiveX combobox? Or are you saying it is a normal Variant variable and you have a validation list combobox in cell D3?

Comment: Hi, UserNonmotorized is a combo box with two anwers (Low/Avg, and High). The combo box answers are in D3 and D4. I am having a difficult time validating these strings. Do i have to convert them to integers? (UserADT <=ADT) and (UserSpeed <Speed) were easy to validate because they are numbers. How should i go about validate Strings?

Comment: @Lizmert. I'm still not following exactly, sorry. I am happy to help you solve this, however. If you could send me your workbook, it would be much easier. My email address is on my profile page.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have sent you an email.